# How to randomize key objects in model form and successfully submit in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, random, django-forms

I am trying to save user response (choice) in my Django application out of a set of values in the source model. The user is expected to select one of the many choices presented on the form (as radio buttons). The source model looks like this:

```
class Emotion(models.Model):
    emote_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, ...)
    emote_state_grp = models.ForeignKey(EmotGroup, ...)     # Grouping of Emotion State
    emote_state = models.CharField(max_length=55, ...)
```

The response/s will be saved in the following model:

```
class EmoteStateResponse(models.Model):
    emote_state_test = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, ...)
    emote_state_selected = models.ForeignKey(Emotion, ...)
```

Using a model form I am able to successfully save user choice (i.e. the "emote_state" value) in table "EmoteStateResponse".

However, as the choices might run into a number of instances of field "emote_state" (individual emotions) of table "Emotion", I am trying to select "at random" only a **minimal** number to display.

To do that, I am trying to randomize the choices in my form that goes like the following:

```
import random

class EmoteTestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmoteTestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.auto_id = True

    class Meta:
        model = EmoteStateResponse
        # ...
        fields = ('emote_state_selected', ...)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmoteTestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        qs_emot_state = Emotion.objects.all().values_list('emot_state_grp__emotion_grp_id', 'emote_id') # "emotion_grp_id": Key Field model "EmotGroup"
        list_qs_emot_state = list(qs_emot_state)
        rand_emot_state_list = list(dict(random.sample(list_qs_emot_state, len(list_qs_emot_state))).values()) # Random values

    # And finally...
    self.fields['emote_state_selected'].queryset = Emotion.objects.filter(emote_id__in=rand_emot_state_list)
```

However, on submit I come across the following error:

> Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available
> choices.

May somebody please point out what I am doing wrong? How may I display the choice field "emote_state_selected" with random values from table "Emotion" and save it?

Comment: The fact that the available options are randomized each time the form is initialized, results in a situation where the available options are not the same when the form is first served to the user, and when the user submits the form. Therefore, the choice of the user might not be present in the random choices, when the form is instantiated after submit.

Comment: You are right in so far as the form failing to submit `successfully` when the page refreshes and a new set of random values are presented. But what I am trying to do is **submit the form with one of the random values**. So before it `fails`, the random values **hold true**, isn't it? Can there be any work around to my problem here?

Comment: How do you define "fails" or "holds true"? From the error you showed, it seems that `is_valid` returns False due to the submitted choice not being one of the available ones. If that is the case, then what I said in my first comments holds true. Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't.